# What is the difference between JSON and data in Node.js request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, request

I want to know about the difference between `json` and `data` in node HTTP requests

```
var http = require('http');

let api = {
    url: "https://someurl/api/ticket/create",
    method: "POST",
    headers:
    {        
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    data:{

    }
}

let apiTwo = {
    url: "https://someurl/api/ticket/create",
    method: "POST",
    headers:
    {        
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    json:{

    }
}


http.request(api,function(err,resp,body){ // 400 for api and 200 for apiTwo 

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(resp);
        console.log(body);
    }
})
```

When I hit the above API with `data` as key in the request, I get `400`. 
When I hit the same API with `json` as key in request I am getting `200`.

In short, my question is this `json` and `data` are configured on the server? What is the difference between them? Which one is preferred when?

Comment: [Neither of the two is documentented](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) so I'm confused why they even affect things.

Comment: I am also confused :)

Comment: Could you add the require line? (e.g. `const http = require('http');`) (In case you use some lib, so that we know.)

Comment: There is already require line, I have not added that in question

Comment: I have added it to question.

Comment: I have wrote the code. With `data` and `json` I hit the API, I got different responses for both of them, 200 and 400. I can't post the api here cause it is not public. I just want to know the difference between `data` and `json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know that after searching a lot, APIs are handled on the server-side for `data` and `json` separately. So when you pass `json` or `data` in your API request, go through the documentation of APIs for the right choice between `json` or `data`.

Answer (score 1):

when we make a post request then the body should be in string format. 
in your first api request the body is an object but not string, that is why you are getting 400

Try bellow to pass data, here I am using json.strinfify to stringify the object

```
let api = {
    url: "https://someurl/api/ticket/create",
    method: "POST",
    headers:
    {        
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    data:JSON.stringfy({})
}
```

In second API call there is no body present in the request so the server will consider body as null so it accepts the request. You are getting 200 because of this but not because of JSON

Comment: Still, it is giving 400. I don't think that body should be string, cause in the header I have specified `Content-Type: application/json`